# Camera Zoom Issue on iPhone X, iPhone XS etc

Tags: swift, uikit, avfoundation

The main issue I am having is with my camera. The main issue is that the camera is zoomed in too far on the iPhone X, Xs, Xs Max, and XR Models.

My camera is a full screen camera which is okay on the smaller iPhones but once I get to the models mentioned above the camera seems to be stuck on the max zoom level. What I really want to accomplish is a nature similar to how instagrams camera works. Where it is full screen on all models up until the iPhone X series and then seemingly respect the edge insets or if it is going to be full screen I want it to not be zoomed in so far the way it is now.

My thought process is to use something like this.

1. Determine the device. I figure I can use something like Device Guru which can be found here to determine the type of device.

GitHub repo can be found here --> https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceGuru

Using this tool or a similar tool I should be able to get the screen dimensions for the device. Then I can do some type of math to determine the proper screen size for the camera view.

Assuming DeviceGuru didn't work I would just use something like this to get the width and height of the screen.

```
// Screen width.
public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}

// Screen height.
public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

This is the block of code I am using to fill the camera. However I want to turn into something that is based on the device size as opposed to just filling it despite the phone

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PreviewView: UIView {
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
        guard let layer = layer as? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer else {
            fatalError("Expected `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` type for layer. Check PreviewView.layerClass implementation.")
        }
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        layer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait


        return layer
    }

    var session: AVCaptureSession? {
        get {
            return videoPreviewLayer.session
        }
        set {
            videoPreviewLayer.session = newValue
        }
    }

    // MARK: UIView

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.self
    }
}
```

I want my camera took look something like this

[image: Instagram]

or this

[image: SnapChat]

Not this ( what my current camera looks like )

[image: My Camera]

I have looked at many questions and nobody has a concrete solution so please don't mark it as a duplicate and please don't say it's just an issue with the iPhone X series.

Comment: The issue can be with the type of camera you are accessing. I had similar issue. Try using .builtInWideAngleCamera

Comment: that worked thank you

Comment: I have posted an answer. Could you please accept and upvote it, if it has helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to update your code with the apt information, since this will give a vague idea to a anyone else with less experience.

Looking at the Images it is clear that the type of camera you are trying to access is quite different than the one you have. With introduction of iPhone 7+ and iPhone X, apple has introduced many different camera devices to the users. All these are accesible through [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/devicetype).

So by looking at what you want to achieve, it is clear that you want more field of view within the screen. This is accessible by `.builtInWideAngleCamera` property of the above given capture device. Changing it to this will solve your problem.

Cheers